# Da pra usar duas colunas de uma mesma tabela num WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

Em um select posso usar no where para filtrar os resultados, duas colunas de uma mesma tabela?

Ex:

```
Select id, idpai, nome FROM tabela Where id=idpai
```

Comment: mas e como vai saber o valor? rsrsrsr

Comment: Pensei nisso tambem! Porem to aprendendo! Então queria ter certeza! Tem uns ninja sabe cada Macete! Talvez existisse um!

Comment: Sem a necessidade de outro select nesse caso seu e complicado, já que vc não sabe o que vai buscar. Ficou confuso o que vc quer. E sua query que usou para explicação vai retomar o que você perguntou.

Comment: Eu também não entendi direito o que você pretende. Pensei que você quisesse algo assim:  `select * from tabela_a where id in ( select id from tabela_b )`   Isso é totalmente correto. Não é isso?

Comment: Não entendi nem a pergunta nem a resposta aceita, pq falam de 2 coisas bem diferentes. É perfeitamente possível usar todas as colunas no próprio select. `SELECT id,nome,idpai WHERE id=idpai`, tou usando duas colunas do próprio select, não? Outro exemplo, com duas tabelas diferentes no mesmo select: `SELECT idbatata FROM batata, idbanana FROM banana WHERE idbanana=idbatata`

Comment: Tinha aceito a pergunta porque pelos comentários deu a entender que não era possível fazer isso que você colocou no comentário! Realmente era isso que eu queria saber! Se era possível usar como comparacao duas colunas de uma mesma tabela!  De fato a pergunta esta mal feita!

Comment: @ivanveloso não teria um caso prático, com dados de exemplo? Fica mais fácil você explicar na pergunta com a estrutura real dos bancos envolvidos, e o que você quer fazer na prática. Muitas vezes ao simplificar o exemplo você acaba tirando partes que seriam fundamentais para solucionar seu problema. Tente postar o caso real que você quer resolver, e não um exemplo. Eu só fiz um contraponto, mas dá pra elaborar melhor a questão explicando com mais detalhes.

Comment: Se fizer algo como `Select id, idpai, nome FROM tabela Where id=idpai`, você irá pegar todas linhas que o ID é igual ao IDPAI, ou seja algo como "idpai: 200 e id: 200", é isso o que quer? Poderia dar um exemplo do resultado final desejado? Pois este é o ponto para entender a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 2):

Você já respondeu sua própria pergunta.

> teria alguma forma onde na hora que o select rodar eu pegar o valor de uma coluna especifica e ja aplicar direto mo WHERE?

"**Na hora que o select rodar**"...
O `select` vai tentar rodar o `where` mas o que você realmente necessita é rodar outro `select` aplicando o `where` de acordo com o retorno deste primeiro.

Se a solução que você busca for retornar apenas campos que se enquadram em um conjunto de valores, então você pode fazer o `select` utilizando a palavra chave `IN`.

```
select ID, valor 
from tabela 
where valor in (8902, 3789, 8452, 7172, 1239);
```

Se você ainda assim "tem necessidade" de realizar essa query, você está aprendendo o conceito um pouquinho errado. Em SQL, é comum se retornar **rows**, de acordo com **values** dentro de **columns**.

Enfim, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não! Não tem necessidade! Queria só saber se era possível mesmo!, o que pela sua resposta e pelos cometários ficou óbvio que não é! Agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode gerar uma sub consulta. Um exemplo:

`SELECT ID, valor FROM tabela WHERE valor IN (SELECT valor FROM tabela2 WHERE valor = [parametro]);`

A sub consulta deve retornar apenas uma coluna, que será justamente usada como filtro na coluna principal. Na sub consulta eu coloquei novamente o campo/coluna valor, mas poderia ser outra, a ressalva é com o retorno da sub consulta, apenas deve retornar uma única coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, de maneira geral há como efetuar o relacionamento com a mesma tabela mas se você tem de fazer isso, revise a estrutura dos dados pois há algo errado.

Você pode utilizar um `JOIN` na mesma tabela, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
t1.id as id_categoria_pai,
t1.nome as nome_categoria_pai,
t2.id,
t2.nome
FROM teste t1
LEFT JOIN teste t2 ON t2.id = t1.idpai
```

Veja funcionando no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd4b3/4)

Comment: Não há necessidade de fazer isso! Minha pergunta tem como intuito aprender sobre. Apenas!

Comment: Sabe! Era um dúvida! Tive que considerar ela!

Comment: Sem problemas, @ivanveloso.